# How to set the default style for tabitem in a tabcontrol's style

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I'm creating a specific style for some TabControl in my application.

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource MyTabControl}">
</TabControl>
```

I want to also style TabItem in the case of this specific TabControl's Style.

For now, I must write :

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource MyTabControl}">
    <TabItem Style="{StaticResource MyTabItem}" Header="First" />
    <TabItem Style="{StaticResource MyTabItem}" Header="Second" />
</TabControl>
```

Instead of having to specify the "MyTabItem" style on each TabItem, is there any way to set the default TabItem style **only in the scope of a specific TabControl Style** ?

I didn't found a way to specify, in the style of my TabControl, which style should be applied on all children TabItems.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTabItem}"/>
```

Comment: Didn't know that ItemContainerStyle was refering to the Tabitems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

put style for target type TabItem as a implicit style under your MyTabItem style resource

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl" x:Key="TabControlStyle">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">

                </Style>
```