# Stop child from inheriting parent Style in TabControls

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF application i have a TabControl that i am binding to a style i created:

On my View:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="6" Style="{DynamicResource SideBarTabControl}">
```

On a separate ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="SideBarTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource TitleFontSize}"/>
</Style>
```

So far so good, things work as expected. The problem is that now all the children of this TabControl, such as a ListView inside a TabItem, is also getting the same FontSize as the TabControl, instead of the default.

I thought that by specifying *TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}"* i would stop the style from being applied to children of different types. What i'm looking for is to actually stop it from affecting EVERYTHING BUT the component that explicitly inherited the style. So how can this be done? I think i am missing something simple...

If i override the font size in my ListView it works, but this means i have to do it for every child, which might become very cumbersome.

I have read this and other questions but i can't find the answer i'm looking for:

[Is it possible to set a style in XAML that selectively affects controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694798/is-it-possible-to-set-a-style-in-xaml-that-selectively-affects-controls)

Comment: You can't apply a TabControl style to a TabItem. Styles in XAML are very different from CSS. They do inherit the parent's TextElement.FontSize, but not by the mechanism you propose. But that's a bit OT -- what you want to do is style the TabItems themselves and explicitly give them whatever font size you want them to use.

Comment: Here's how to set the TabItem style: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4693910/424129

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain myself well. I am styling the TabControl, increasing the font size in the tab, and eventually background color, and this works. But its also affecting components inside the TabItems. I want to stop the style from cascading down

Comment: If you want to change the appearance of the TabItems, style the TabItems.

Comment: Actually, when you say "inside the tab items", do you mean the tab HEADER content, or the tab PAGE content? The TabItem style affects the headers. But whichever it is, if you want to change its appearance, apply a style to it.

Comment: Yes i just want to style the headers of the TabControl, and i am using a style like i showed. Just tried applying the style to each TabItem instead of the TabControl, problem is the same. Shouldn't the x:Key and the TargetType values restrict the binding of the style only to the element that i explicitly binded it to?

Comment: If that's the case your Style needs target TabItem and you would be setting the template for `HeaderTemplate` like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199403/wpf-tabitem-headertemplate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me. The part that's doing the work is `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle`. It applies a font size only to the header content.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style 
            TargetType="TabItem" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}"
            >
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl 
                            TextElement.FontSize="20" 
                            Content="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" 
                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabItem Header="Foo">
        <Label Content="Bar" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Baz">
        <Label Content="Bar" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks again Ed. I even moved the Style to my ResourceDictionary, so everything is tidy. I'm guessing this issue will show up again with other object types, so i will study this solution and learn more about DataTemplates.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop it, it's not the style causing this unwanted trickle-down effect you want rid of; it's just how WPF controls work.

What you will have to do to stop this is write another style for your tab items to intercept the one being inherited from the TabControl.
I suggest writing this style inside your existing TabControl style, inside the Style.Resources tag like so:

```
 <Style x:Key="SideBarTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}" >
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9001"/>
                        <!-- Any other setters you want for TabItems -->
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource TitleFontSize}"/>
            </Style>
```

By making a style inside your other style's resources, it will be carried with it, and by not specifying any `x:Key` for the `TabItem` style -  it will apply it to any `TabItem` not ordered to have a specific style, becoming the default style for any `TabItem` you make inside the `TabControl` now.

Comment: This would apply to font size of everything in TabItem though, OP specified just Headers right?

Comment: Tried it and it looks like @ChrisW. is right. OP will have to either explicitly set TextElement.FontSize for the content of the tab pages, or else explicitly set it for the tab header content.